# Android Leanback BrowseFragment refill adapter causing items to move to the right

Tags: android, leanback

When I refill the adapter of BrowseFragmnet and the header column is not showing, The items are moving to the right, causing an empty space between the Header column and the RowsFragment as the following image. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

This is how I am updating the adapter as an example:

```
  adapter.clear();
  ...
  adapter.add(new ListRow(new IconHeaderItem(0,category,featureCat.Icon), fragmentAdapter));
  ...
  if(adapter.size()>0)
    adapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(0,(adapter.size()-1));
```

Comment: Add your xmls also ! It may be possible that you have some padding/margins in your xml's.

Comment: there is no padding in xml, first load works perfectly with no margins, this happens only on reload,
the problem seems to me that the headers fragment should be expanded, this gap is equal to the header fragment width.